# Why does an exported module error report that a defined function "is not a function"

Tags: javascript, node.js, mochawesome

This is where I define my functions and export them using module.exports

```
class GITHelper extends Helper {

addLatestReport(){
  simpleGitPromise.addRemote(date,remote);
    return simpleGitPromise.add('.')
      .then(
          (addSuccess) => {
            console.log(addSuccess);
          }, (failedAdd) => {
            console.log('adding files failed');
      });
}

commitLatestReport(){
  console.log("Committing...");
  return simpleGit.commit("Latest output from Automated UI Testing", "./output");
}

pushLatestReport() {
    console.log('Pushing...');
    return simpleGit.push(remote);
}

}

module.exports = GITHelper;
```

I require this module in another node dependency file (mochawesome) using this

```
var gitHelper = require('../../../helpers/GITHelper.js');
```

and then I call the functions like so:

```
async function gitSender()
{
 await gitHelper.addLatestReport();
 await gitHelper.commitLatestReport();
 await gitHelper.pushlatestReport();
 console.log("Upload completed");
}
```

"TypeError: gitHelper.addLatestReport is not a function"

Are these not defined functions? Are they not being exported correctly?

Comment: import { gitHelper } from '../../../helpers/GITHelper.js'. because there is only module exports

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The methods in your `GITHelper` class are instance method (not static method). `addLatestReport`, `commitLatestReport`, `pushLatestReport` are in `GITHelper.prototype`.  So the methods become meaningful from instance (`const gitHelper = new GitHelper; gitHelper.addLatestReport();`).

Try make a instance of `GitHelper` to use the methods

```js
const GitHelper = require('../../../helpers/GITHelper.js');
const gitHelper = new GitHelper();

async function gitSender()
{
 await gitHelper.addLatestReport();
 await gitHelper.commitLatestReport();
 await gitHelper.pushlatestReport();
 console.log("Upload completed");
}
```

---

Another options is to make static method. If the methods don't use `this` keyword, the methods can be static.

```js
class ConsoleExample {
   static sayHello() {
      console.log('hello')
   }
}


ConsoleExample.sayHello();
```

Comment: as a third alternative, you can export the class instance. `export default new GitHelper()`, then all importing modules can share that instance instead of creating their own.